# Swift return Alamofire error in completion handler

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to write an API manager for my app and want to return any response error to my calling function. Should I test the error here and return it as a third variable in my completion handler or can I get it from HTTPURLResponse? Is there any better way to do this?

I have the following code

```
func myQuery(router: myRouter, completionHandler: @escaping (HTTPURLResponse?, [String: Any]?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(router)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if response.result.error != nil {

            }  
            else {              

// ... save auth token 

completionHandler(response.response, response.result.value as? [String: Any])
    }
```

If the best way to handle this is to return an error as well would this code be correct?

```
func myQuery(router: myRouter, completionHandler: @escaping (String?, HTTPURLResponse?, [String: Any]?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(router)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if response.result.error != nil {
                completionHandler(response.result.error as? String, response.response, response.result.value as? [String: Any])
            }
            else {

            completionHandler(nil, response.response, response.result.value as? [String: Any])
    }
```

To add more context I am trying to replace similar to this code in calling functions

```
Alamofire.request((url),
   method: .get,
   parameters: nil,
   encoding: URLEncoding.default,
   headers: ["Authorization" : requestHeader, "APi-Key" : token])
            .responseJSON { response -> Void in

            if response.result.error != nil {
                // Handle Error
                completionHandler(nil, response.result.error as NSError?)
            }
```

Comment: I would return `response` (the returned parameter of the request) and handle everything in the completion handler. By the way `as! String?` is a contradiction in terms

Comment: I'm unsure how to do this. Could you give an example preferably as an answer, please? I'm new at this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Alamofire` but instead of `(String?, HTTPURLResponse?, [String: Any]?` return the – most likely non-optional –  type of `response` and call `completionHandler(response)`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to extract an error from response. The compiler wanted `as? String!` I changed it to `as? String`